# Deleting an item from a collection in f, using React Redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete an item from a collection in Firestore by referencing the id of the selected item. I'm successfully passing on the id by mapDispatchToProps until the action but stops short when trying to delete in Firestore by the delete(). I think the problem may be in the my method to delete in firestore as it stops there. Can anyone kindly please tell me what could be wrong with my code?

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { firestoreConnect } from "react-redux-firebase";
import { compose } from 'redux'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import moment from 'moment'
import { deleteProject } from '../../store/actions/projectActions'

const handleClick = (e, prop) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    deleteProject(prop)
    console.log(prop)
}

const ProjectDetails = (props) => {
    const { auth, project } = props;
    if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin' />
    if (project) {
        return (
        <div className="container section project-details">
            <div className="card z-depth-0">
               // content here
                </div>
                <button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, props.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    } else {
        return (
        <div className="container center">
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
            )
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const id = ownProps.match.params.id;
    const projects = state.firestore.data.projects;
    const project = projects ? projects[id] : null
    return {
        project: project,
        id: id,
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}
const matchDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        deleteProject: (id) => dispatch(deleteProject(id))
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'projects' }
    ])
)(ProjectDetails)
```

```
export const deleteProject = (id) => {
  console.log("dispatch", id) \\ successfully shows "dispatch", id
  return(dispatch, getState, {getFirestore}) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    firestore.collection('projects').doc(id).delete()
      .then(() => {
        console.log('deleted') \\ does not show deleted here
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_PROJECT_SUCCESS' });
      }).catch(err => {
        dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_PROJECT_ERROR' });
      })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the imported version of `deleteProject` rather than the `mapDispatchToProps` version. This is a common gotcha.

One way to fix this (and prevent it happening in future) is to rename your action in your mapDispatchToProps to something different:

```
const matchDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        dispatchDeleteProject: (e, id) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            dispatch(deleteProject(id))
        })
    }
}
```

Then you can destructure this out of your props and call it:

```
const ProjectDetails = (props) => {
    const { auth, project, dispatchDeleteProject } = props;
    if (!auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/signin' />
    if (project) {
        return (
        <div className="container section project-details">
            <div className="card z-depth-0">
               // content here
                </div>
                <button onClick={e=>dispatchDeleteProject(e, props.id)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your action `deleteProject` is not getting called from redux's `dispatch`.

If you will observer correctly, in your `handleClick` function, you are calling `deleteProject` function function action directly.

`handleClick` function should call `deleteProject` function from prop like this.

Your handleClick function should be -

```
const handleClick = (e, id, deleteProject) => { // passing deleteProject function from prop
    e.preventDefault()
    deleteProject(id)
    console.log(id)
}
```

You HTML should be -

```
<button onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, props.id, props.deleteProject)}>Delete</button>
```